# it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: cordova-2.0.0

I just started to learn Cordova. I created a project  according to [this](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/#get-started) url.This project runs OK in the Ripple emulator.But when I try to run it in Google Android Emulator.It can not get weather,and display the following information:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+weather.forecast+where+location=98052&format=json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

jquery-2.1.4.min.js (4,14349)
```

Should I do something else to make this project run normal in Google Android Emulator.

Comment: Thanks to Lakhan for helping to edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://content-security-policy.com/#source_list

fix:

in sorce app directory:

www\index.html

in

https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

i change 'self' by '*'

content="default-src *